# flutter_blue and background service : MissingPluginException No implementation found on channel

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, background-service

I want to make bluetooth work (connection to a device) in the background. but I get the following error:

```
E/flutter (15225): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method isAvailable on channel plugins.pauldemarco.com/flutter_blue/methods)
E/flutter (15225): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (15225): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15225): #1      FlutterBlue._setLogLevelIfAvailable (package:flutter_blue/src/flutter_blue.dart:77:9)
E/flutter (15225): <asynchronous suspension>
```

To reproduce the problem it's very simple:

1. Create a Flutter app
2. Add the following packages:

   **flutter pub add flutter_blue**

   **flutter pub add flutter_background_service**

Then start the background service and trigger it

```
    void main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      FlutterBackgroundService.initialize(onStart);
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    void onStart() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
      service.onDataReceived.listen((event) {
        if (event!["bluetooth"] == "start") {
          FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
          flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));
    
          var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
            for (ScanResult r in results) {
              print('${r.device.name} found! rssi: ${r.rssi}');
            }
          });
    
          flutterBlue.stopScan();
          return;
        }
    
      });
    
      service.setForegroundMode(false);
    }
```

```
    IconButton(
      onPressed: (){
        FlutterBackgroundService().sendData({"bluetooth": "start"},);
        },
      icon: Icon(Icons.bluetooth),
    )
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: did you try with flutter clean & re-run the app?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I forgot to specify but if I put the code "bluetooth" in the "onPressed" of the button it works fine. It is only in the "background" (via the onStart function) that I have the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FlutterBluePlus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus) plugin which is more up to date...

It's almost a drop-in replacement : all you have to do is replace `FlutterBlue` by `FlutterBluePlus` in your code...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, [This](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_background) package is working fine. I have modified this package locally, and it is functioning well on Android. Since this package is new, I think it is still a work in progress.